# Why does Yeoman scaffolding for AngularJS use the same module for each tab

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection, yeoman-generator-angular, angularjs-module

I'm new to AngularJS and setting up my projects with Yeoman. Yeoman generates a scaffold for a basic AngularJS tab nav web site controlling tab content in the following way.

app.js:

```
'use strict';

angular
  .module('ang1050315App', [
    'ngAnimate',
    'ngCookies',
    'ngResource',
    'ngRoute',
    'ngSanitize',
    'ngTouch',
    'formModule'
  ])

  .controller('HeaderController', ['$scope',  
  }]).

  .config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl'
      })
      .when('/about', {
        templateUrl: 'views/about.html',
        controller: 'AboutCtrl'
      })
            .when('/contact', {
        templateUrl: 'views/contact.html',
        controller: 'ContactCtrl'
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
  });
```

And then the module content for each tab is basically the same, for example.

about.js:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('ang1050315App')
  .controller('AboutCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.awesomeThings = [
      'HTML5 Boilerplate',
      'AngularJS',
      'Karma'
    ];

  });
```

html template:

```
   <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" ng-controller="HeaderController">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li ng-class="{ active: isActive('/')}"><a href="#/">Home</a></li>
            <li ng-class="{ active: isActive('/about')}"><a href="#/about">About</a></li>
            <li ng-class="{ active: isActive('/contact')}"><a href="#/contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

What I'm wondering is, why use the same name module for each tab i.e. "ang1050315App". This seems like a disadvantage because it forces each tab to have the same module dependencies.

Comment: really depends on what generator you are using and whether it doesn't have parameters available for module name and controller name along with other options. Not liking it...try another one

Comment: It's not that I don't like it, I'm just trying to understand their design reasoning.

Comment: doesn't make a lot of sense to me either. If using node take a look at some of the MEAN stacks  like meanjs

Comment: What would you gain by having a separate module for each tab? Why do you think it would be better? Modules are just a way to arrange components. The whole JS code needs to be loaded by the unique HTML page whatever you do.

Comment: What if I have one tab that has a different dependency than all the other tabs. Doesn't using the same module force all the tabs to have the same dependency set?

Answer (score 1):

The module name, in this case: `ang1050315App`, is just an identifier for your entire app. All that's happening in your generated code is that each `controller` is being assigned to the specific app module (ang1050315App). In other words, "the controller 'AboutCtrl' is part of the project with the module name 'ang1050315App'".

If you wanted your code to be a bit less verbose, you could reference your Angular project using a variable instead (e.g. `myApp`):

```
var myApp = angular.module('ang1050315App', [
                'ngAnimate',
                'ngCookies',
                'ngResource',
                'ngRoute',
                'ngSanitize',
                'ngTouch',
                'formModule'
            ]);
```

And for your controllers:

```
myApp.controller('AboutCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.awesomeThings = [
      'HTML5 Boilerplate',
      'AngularJS',
      'Karma'
    ];
});
```

Notice how you no longer have to refer to the module name from the `controller`.

Answer (score 0):

You can just assign yr angular app name to a variable and export it.
If you dont export "app", jshint will show error inside yr other js files.

```
'use strict';
/* global app:true */
/* exported app */

/**
* @ngdoc overview
* @name yrAppName
* @description
* # yrAppName
*
* Main module of the application.
*/
var app = angular.module('yrAppName', []);
```

then inside yr controller, directive or service...

somecontroller.js

```
app.controller('controllerName', []);
```

somefactory.js

```
app.factory('factoryName',[]);
```